# lxc error: saving config file for the container failed

Tags: lxc, lxd

I recently upgraded my lxd to 2.20-0ubuntu4~16.04.1~ppa, but now i cant start my imported containers.

I can successfully import a containers, with lxd import NAME
and i can do lxc config show NAME and it show the config.

but when i go to start it, then it says:

```
lxc start web01

error: saving config file for the container failed
Try `lxc info --show-log web01` for more info**

lxc info --show-log web01

Name: web01
Remote: unix://
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2017/11/18 20:34 UTC
Status: Stopped
Type: persistent
Profiles: v41
```

Log:

if i run in debug (lxc start --debug web01) then i get the following at the end of the debug which doesnt seem to help:

```
DBUG[11-18|20:41:28] Got operation from LXD
DBUG[11-18|20:41:28]
    {
            "id": "8c760a1d-f1d4-418b-a7bc-fce2cb19e878",
            "class": "task",
            "created_at": "2017-11-18T20:41:28.572544339Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-18T20:41:28.572544339Z",
            "status": "Running",
            "status_code": 103,
            "resources": {
                    "containers": [
                            "/1.0/containers/web01"
                    ]
            },
            "metadata": null,
            "may_cancel": false,
            "err": ""
    }
DBUG[11-18|20:41:28] Sending request to LXD                   etag=     method=GET url=http://unix.socket/1.0/operations/8c760a1d-f1d4-418b-a7bc-fce2cb19e878
DBUG[11-18|20:41:28] Got response struct from LXD
DBUG[11-18|20:41:28]
    {
            "id": "8c760a1d-f1d4-418b-a7bc-fce2cb19e878",
            "class": "task",
            "created_at": "2017-11-18T20:41:28.572544339Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-18T20:41:28.572544339Z",
            "status": "Running",
            "status_code": 103,
            "resources": {
                    "containers": [
                            "/1.0/containers/web01"
                    ]
            },
            "metadata": null,
            "may_cancel": false,
            "err": ""
    }
error: saving config file for the container failed
Try `lxc info --show-log web01` for more info
```

can anyone help show why it cant save its config?

Answer (score 0):

ok so for info for anyone who gets, this it might be because in the ppa for 2.20 i was offered the snap release instead, and installed.
however on the snap relase it changes the directory to be /var/snap
e.g /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pool/ is the new /var/lib/lxd/storage-pool

this is probably ok if you dont symlink the pool and containers like i do.
So the /var/lib/lxd/containers breaks in the snap as its trying to point to /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers.

I have since backported the lxd to 16.04 and then changed the symlinks to be as they were without the snap, but i think they would work equally well in the snap.
for info for the backport to 16.04:
apt install -t xenial-backports lxd lxd-client